# How to Insert data in table when Foreign Key is not a primary key

Tags: sql, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

I created a Model with Entity Framework Code First and have two classes

**Product.cs**

```
public class Product
    {
        public Product()
        {
            Certificates = new HashSet<Certificate>();
        }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int ProductCode { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string SubType { get; set; }
        public int RelatedProductId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string DescriptionSpanish { get; set; }
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        public string CertificateDescription { get; set; }
        public string QBItemCode { get; set; }
        public string QBDescCode { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Certificate> Certificates { get; set; }
    }
```

**Certificate.cs**

```
public class Certificate
    {
        public int CertificateId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Course { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateGranted { get; set; }
        public string NameOnCertificate { get; set; }
        public int FinalExamQuestionsCorrect { get; set; }
        public int FinalExamQuestionsTotal { get; set; }
        public string ClientIPAddress { get; set; }
        public int ProductCode { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

**ProductConfiguration.cs**

```
public class ProductConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
    {
        public ProductConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(p => p.ProductId);

            Property(p => p.ProductId)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);


            Property(p => p.ProductCode)
                 .HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
                    new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("AK_Product_ProductCode") { IsUnique = true }));


        }
    }
```

**CertificateConfiguration.cs**

```
public class CertificateConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Certificate>
    {
        public CertificateConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(c => c.CertificateId);

            Property(c => c.CertificateId)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);



            Property(p => p.ProductCode).HasColumnName("ProductId");


            HasRequired(c => c.ApplicationUser)
               .WithMany(u => u.Certificates)
               .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);

            HasRequired(c => c.Product)
               .WithMany(p => p.Certificates)
               .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProductCode);
        }
    }
```

Notice, I created a `Foreign Key` `ProductCode` (rename it to `ProductId`) in `Certificate Table`.

I also seeded `Product` `table` with some data in which the `ProductId` generated by `database` and `ProductCode` that I manually defined. The problem is when I am trying to insert a record in `Certificate` `table` by running a `sql` query in which I defined a `foreign key` that's actually a `ProductCode` (not `ProductId`), it throws an error

**SQL QUERY:**

```
Insert into [dbo].[Certificates]
values (
'TestType','TestCourse',GETUTCDATE(),'TestName',1,5,
'127.0.0.1',201,'userId'
)
```

**201 is the ProductCode in query that exist in Product table**

**Error**

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Certificates_dbo.Products_ProductId". The conflict occurred in database "myDatabse", table "dbo.Products", column 'ProductId'.
```

I am not sure why it's looking for Primary Key `ProductId`. It should look for the `ProductCode` in `Product` table weather it exist or not.

Comment: You said you're trying to insert into the Certificate table with a sql query ... could you post a sample of that?

Comment: Please see the update

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're running into a limitation of EF whereby your FK on the dependent end of the relationship has to refer back to the PK on the principal end. When you configure the relationship between `Product` and `Certificates` here:

```
HasRequired(c => c.Product)
  .WithMany(p => p.Certificates)
  .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProductCode);
```

this establishes the foreign key relationship between the Product primary key - `Product.ProductId` - and the foreign key you defined - `Certificate.ProductCode` (named `Certificate.ProductId` in your table).

While the database will support FK referring back to a unique key in your table, EF does not support it (at this time).

Here are a few other SO questions that cover this issue:

[How to get EF6 to honor Unique Constraint (on FK) in Association/Relationship multiplicity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609023/how-to-get-ef6-to-honor-unique-constraint-on-fk-in-association-relationship-mu)

[Database first Entity Framework mapping unique foreign keys as one to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061152/database-first-entity-framework-mapping-unique-foreign-keys-as-one-to-many)

And here's the official feature request to add this feature to EF:

[Unique Constraint (i.e. Candidate Key) Support](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support)

According to the comments, it looks like they are working adding this in EF7.

Comment: So, There isn't a way to establish relationship between `Product.ProductCode` and `Certificate.ProductCode` (named `Certificate.ProductId` ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You might be able to fake it by making `Product.ProductCode` your primary key, but this may have consequences for other relationships you may need to define.